# not able to add a imageview to custom adapter to be shown into a gridview , it is giving classcast exception on setimageresource

Tags: casting

```
                  package com.ettv.tv.forealz;

               import android.content.Context;
               import android.util.Log;
               import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                  import android.view.View;
               import android.view.ViewGroup;
               import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
               import android.widget.ImageView;
                import android.widget.TextView;
               import android.widget.Toast;

                import androidx.leanback.widget.ArrayObjectAdapter;
                 import androidx.leanback.widget.HeaderItem;
                   import androidx.leanback.widget.ListRow;

                   import com.ettv.tv.R;
                    `import com.ettv.tv.forealz.model.ModelStore;
                    `import com.ettv.tv.forealz.model.Topic;
                      import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

               import java.util.ArrayList;
              import java.util.List;

                  `import static com.ettv.tv.MovieList.list;
```

// it is the custom adapter
                `public class CustomAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

`
                     @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                      return topics3.size();
    }

```
                 @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                 return position;
}

                 @Override
                 public long getItemId(int position) {
```

`                  return position;
    }

```
                  @Override
                  public View getView(int position, View convertView, 
    ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = thisInflater.inflate( R.layout.row_item, parent, 
   false );
        //TextView textHeading = (TextView) 
         convertView.findViewById(R.id.petnames);
        ImageView thumbnailImage = (ImageView) 
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);




        final List list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (Topic topic : topics3) {



      thumbnailImage.setImageResource(topics3.get(position).getmDrawable());
        }
```

}

```
}




                  return convertView;
}
```

private List topics3;
    private LayoutInflater thisInflater;

```
               public CustomAdapter2(Context con, List<Topic> topics2) {
```

`                      this.thisInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);

this.topics3=topics2;

```
    Log.d("check7",this.topics3.toString());
 Log.d("check8", String.valueOf(topics2.size()));



}
```

}

}

Comment: i am getting this class cast exception               Process: com.ettv.tv, PID: 26641
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.ettv.tv.forealz.model.Topic
        at com.ettv.tv.forealz.CustomAdapter2.getView(CustomAdapter2.java:73)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2388)
        at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22097)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6604)

Comment: i have resolved it myself